# Statement about independence of random variables

Tags: pr.probability

If I have 2 random variables $\xi, \eta$ and $\forall n,m \ \mathbb E\xi^n\eta^m=\mathbb E\xi^n \mathbb E\eta^m$, does this imply that $\xi,\eta$ are independent? How to show it?

Comment: isn't this what is called [sub-independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subindependence) ?

Comment: See [this question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463082/does-independence-of-moments-imply-independence).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. Indeed, let $X:=\xi$ and $Y:=\eta$. Let $U$ and $V$ be any independent random variables (r.v.'s) with different distributions but with the same finite moments of all orders: 
$$EU^m=EV^m=:\mu_m$$
for all natural $m$. A standard example of the distributions of such r.v.'s $U$ and $V$ is given in [the answer by saz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166637/do-moments-define-distributions).

Let the cumulative distribution function (cdf) $F_{X,Y}$ of the random pair $(X,Y)$ be the half-and-half mixture of the cdf's $F_{U,V}$ and $F_{V,U}$, so that 
\begin{equation*}
 F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{F(x)G(y)+G(x)F(y)}2 \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
for all real $x,y$, where $F$ and $G$ are the cdf's of $U$ and $V$, respectively. Then for the cdf's $F_X$ and $F_Y$ one has $F_X=F_Y=\frac{F+G}2$ and hence 
\begin{equation*}
4[F_X(x)F_Y(y)-F_{X,Y}(x,y)]=[F(x)-G(x)][F(y)-G(y)]\ne0
\end{equation*}
for some real $x,y$, so that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

However, 
\begin{equation*}
 EX^mY^n=\tfrac12\,EU^m\, EV^n+\tfrac12\,EV^m\,EU^n=\mu_m\mu_n=EX^m\,EY^n \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
for all natural $m,n$.

---

**Details on (2), in response to comments by the OP:** To simplify the matter, here we may use the fact that in the mentioned standard example of the distributions of r.v.'s $U$ and $V$, these r.v.'s actually have probability density functions (pdf's), say $f$ and $g$. Then one may rewrite (1) as
\begin{equation*}
 f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{f(x)g(y)+g(x)f(y)}2 \tag{1a}
\end{equation*}
for all real $x,y$, where $f_{X,Y}$ is the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$. So, 
\begin{multline*}
 EX^mY^m=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^my^n f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx\,dy \\ 
=\frac12\,\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^m f(x)\,dx\ \int_{-\infty}^\infty y^n g(y)\,dy+\frac12\,\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^m g(x)\,dx\ \int_{-\infty}^\infty y^n f(y)\,dy \\ 
=\tfrac12\,EU^m\, EV^n+\tfrac12\,EV^m\,EU^n
=\mu_m\mu_n=EX^m\,EY^n. \tag{2a}
\end{multline*}

Comment: Can you explain me please why $E X^mY^n=1/2EU^mEV^n+1/2EV^mEU^n$? @Iosif Pinelis

Comment: @user157895564 : One way to do this is to use (1) to write the following: 
$EX^mY^m=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^my^n dF_{X,Y}(x,y)
=\tfrac12\,\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^m dF(x)\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^n dG(y)+\tfrac12\,\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^m dG(x)\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^n dF(y)=\tfrac12\,EU^m\, EV^n+\tfrac12\,EV^m\,EU^n$.

Comment: Why second equality is correct? @Iosif Pinelis

Comment: @user157895564 : This equality immediately follows by (1) and the definitions of the Lebesgue--Stieltjes integrals with respect to $dF_{X,Y}$, $dF$, and $dG$. To simplify this, we may use the fact that in the cited example of the distributions of r.v.'s $U$ and $V$, these r.v.'s actually have pdf's. I have added this detail to the answer.

Comment: But it doesn't work, isn't it? $(F_{X,Y})'_x=f_{X,Y}$ only if $G=g,F=f$, but $f$ is always summable, but $F$ is not. Or I'm missed something?

Comment: @user157895564 : One never has $(F_{X,Y})'_x=f_{X,Y}$ or $G=g$ or $F=f$, and nothing of these sorts was used in the answer. One does have $(F_{X,Y})''_{xy}=f_{X,Y}$ whenever $f_{X,Y}$ is continuous, say. (See e.g. (Eq.5) in Section "Continuous case" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Continuous_case).

Comment: Previous comment continued: However, good news may be that one doesn't have to necessarily understand formula (2) in the answer, which is in terms of Lebesgue--Stieltjes integrals. It is enough to understand formula (2a), which is in terms of pdf's only and hence does not require understanding relations between the joint pdf and the joint cdf.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear for me.